# Computing the integral of a solution of the wave equation over the whole space

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We suppose $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R})$ solves 
\begin{align}
u_{tt} &= \Delta u\\
u(x,0) =f(x) &\text{, } u_t(x,0) = g(x)
\end{align}
where $f, g \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x,t)dx$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure how to go about this, so I set $E(t)$ equal to the above integral in hopes to find some simple ODE that $E(t)$ solves and go from there. I'm not sure this is the right approach though, so any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \int_V u(x,t) \, dx = \int_V u_{tt} \, dx = \int_V \Delta u \, dx = \int_{\partial V} \nabla u \cdot dS, $$
using differentiation under the integral sign and the Divergence Theorem. If we take $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, the last term vanishes because at finite time the solution to the wave equation with compact initial conditions is compact (information propagates along characteristics, which are finite-speed curves for the wave equation). Hence we must have
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x,t) \, dx = At+B. $$
Setting $t=0$ gives $B = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x,0) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \, dx $, and $A$ is obtained similarly.